How to tell ogr2ogr/GDAL not to correct any geometry?
I need to import geometries as they are (even invalid) into PostGIS. I use ogr2ogr in a Python script to import the shapefiles.
I was able to avoid most corrections removing the -makevalid option and adding -nlt GEOMETRY but I still get this warning:
Warning 1: mydata.shp contains polygon(s) with rings with invalid winding order. Autocorrecting them, but that shapefile should be corrected using ogr2ogr for example.

I think this autocorrection comes from the GDAL library. If possible, is there a way to tell GDAL not to autocorrect the geometries?
Or if not possible, does anyone know if this correction could alter the shape of the polygon in any way?

I looks like the geometries are invalid already in the shapefile,  so not following the outer ring clockwise and holes counterclockwise rule https://www.esri.com/content/dam/esrisites/sitecore-archive/Files/Pdfs/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf. Can you share a sample? Which software creates such shapefiles?

Yes, the geometries are invalid in the raw data. It comes from (poor quality) governmental data that needs to be imported as they are so that the import doesn't alter the official data. The shapefile can be downloaded here: https://cadastre.data.gouv.fr/data/etalab-cadastre/latest/shp/france/cadastre-france-communes-shp.zip I don't know the software they used to create it

I do not understand how fixing the windings of the polygon rings can alter the official data in any harmful way. The polygons will stay in the same place, the areas will not change.

Maybe not but I need to be 100% sure... So the best would be not to correct anything if possible so that the invalid geom can just be reported... or if the algo used for such correction guarantees that the shape is not affected in any way, it could be OK too

Maybe you can import the shape as a geometryless table, with a select statement converting the geometry to WKT?

I don't agree with you about what is best. I think the best option is to contact the data provider and ask them to fix their data. Second best it to fix geometries on your side. And even it may be possible to keep the geometries untouched by saving them as WKT as suggested above, PostGIS and GDAL will correct and unify the winding order when data are saved into any GIS format.

I agree but contacting a governmental agency and discussing about their data for the whole country will possibly take age until having a result, but one can have surprises. Altering the geoms is not an option in my case. So the "best" solution has been decided not to alter the official geoms and just report the invalid ones as needed. I didn't mean it's the best solution in general.
I will look into the WKT option, thanks for the suggestion. I was just hoping there was an option in GDAL to disable the autocorrection as I haven't found anything in the doc.

$0.02: garbage IN, garbage OUT ... and let's not forget that different formats / software / functionalities can get distinctively artistic in how they handle geometric errors. What about fixing the geometries, then run a comparison between the original shapefile and the corrected layer then handle the cases - if any - where the correction introduce a visible difference. Beware if you have "right" and "left" attributes (though it is more common on lines than polygons)

@JGH Yes, that's a good option too. Originally, the geometries were corrected. There are plenty of other layers coming from many different data providers, not only the example layer above. Many of these official layers have invalid geoms. It's not as simple as it seems with the example layer above. Some polys changed into lines or points with the geom corrections and it's a no go in my case. So, a solution could be the correct what can be corrected without significant difference (and find a way to systematically measure the difference).

It adds complexity in the processing so for now a general approach was not to alter anything and report invalid geoms as needed.

How can correcting the winding order affect the actual geometry of a polygon in any meaningful way?  It's just changing the order of the vertices from clockwise to anti-clockwise, or vice versa.  That won't affect the actual area covered by a polygon.  Do you have any reason to believe that it would have any meaningful impact on the correctness or accuracy of the polygons?  It seems that you're seeing  a problem that isn't actually there (if I understand the situation correctly).

I'm not sure, that's why I asked, if it's guaranteed 100% that the shape of the poly will not change with the gdal autocorrecting algo and how it is implemented, it's all OK for me

Setting the OGR_ORGANIZE_POLYGONS configuration option to SKIP will avoid GDAL doing this interpretation.
However, if the ring ordering is not correct, the only thing gdal can do without any interpretation is to treat each ring as an outer ring, which I doubt is better than the default behaviour. The only thing GDAL does is reordering the points, so it is not a very intrusive change.
However, if you would want to use/try it, you can specify the option by adding these parameters:
--config OGR_ORGANIZE_POLYGONS SKIP


Thanks, I overlooked this option obviously! I will have a try
